# Convert Data type Int to Varchar SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016. My dates are already of type `varchar(50)`. I want case expression to create column as `Varchar`.

But using the following statement

```
Case 
    when task_completed_date is not >= 1 
       Then '1'  
    when SUM(DATEDIFF (DAY, task_started_date, task_completed_date)+1) <= 0 
       Then 'Ongoing'
End
```

is throwing an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Ongoing' to data type int

Please help! Thank you

Comment: If the datatype is varchar they are not dates. They are instead string representations of dates which is not a good idea. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type Also, as posted your code would fail because there are syntax errors in your case expression.

Comment: Please show us the full query.

Answer (score 1):

The *return type* of a `CASE` expression in T-SQL must be the **same** for all paths and alternatives - this is **not** the case in your situation.

When the return types of different `WHEN` paths is not the same, SQL Server will try to convert all return values to a common type - based on [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) as documented in MSDN.

Here, `INT` has a **higher precedence** than `VARCHAR`, so SQL Server is trying to convert all return values to `INT` - and quite obviously, 'Ongoing' doesn't really convert well to an `INT` ......

So you need to **either** convert all possible return values from your `CASE` to be valid `INT` - or go the other way and make all return values `VARCHAR`:

```
Case 
    when task_completed_date is not >= 1 
       Then CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(5))
    when SUM(DATEDIFF (DAY, task_started_date, task_completed_date)+1) <= 0 
       Then 'Ongoing'
End
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is somewhere else ,share your full context and keep date data on  date type not `varchar` type , below example is work fine

```
select case when 1>=2 then '1' else 'Ongoing' end
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d47f4d8333fc1cfc606e8c22f942af9

Comment: if I add int for example '2' instead of 'ongoing' then it works fine. I think problem is between '1' and 'ongoing'. I want the output as 'varchar' not 'int'. that will solve the problem. but I don't know how to change output to 'varchar'.